# Return the row number of a match in a 2d array

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried to find a solution to this online and for whatever reason simply cannot locate anything (perhaps my search skills are lacking).  I have what I feel is a fairly simple query.

I am declaring an array and assigning data to it using the following, which I have confirmed is working:

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

Now, given that this is a 2-dimensional array (only 2 columns of data), I want to then use a match-type of function to return the row number associated with a value in column 1 of the array.  My end goal is to then use that to call the corresponding value in column 2 of the array - essentially building an index/match type of scenario but in VBA.  However, the Application.Match function fails as this isn't a 1-dimensional array.  See example below:

```
1|Apple   |Fruit
2|Tomato  |Fruit
3|Carrot  |Vegetable
4|Zucchini|Vegetable
```

What I am trying to achieve is something like MATCH("Tomato", arr(), 0) to get the result of "2" being the row number associate with Tomato.  I only need to do my search in column 1 of the array.  Does anyone perhaps have any suggestions on the easiest way to do this?

Thanks a mil!

Comment: Loop over the array use a simple `For...` loop?

Comment: To find data in a range, use `Range.Find` method. That's what its designed for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to avoid a loop, you can slice an array, thus:

```
Sub x()

  Dim arr As Variant, v As Variant

  arr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
  v = Application.Match("Tomato", Application.Index(arr, , 1), 0) 'look in first column
  If IsNumeric(v) Then MsgBox v
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @SJR, super useful method, especially in python! +1